# Can I use itertools::PutBack::put_back in a loop?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rust-itertools

My use case:

- Loop over string
- React to each character in a lexical analyzer state machine
- On seeing some characters, realize that the previous character was the end of its token
- finish up the token
- transition back to the **Empty** state (meaning no token is partially constructed)
- push the "extra" character back onto the iterator with `put_back`
- continue the state machine processing, where the put back character will be available for the first character in the next token.

Here is an example of an attempt:

```
use itertools::put_back; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let hello = "Hello world".to_owned();
    let hello_iter = hello.chars();
    let mut putback_iterator = put_back(hello_iter);
    let mut already_putback = false;
    for c in putback_iterator {
        if c == 'd' && !already_putback {
            putback_iterator.put_back('!');
            already_putback = true;
        }
        println!("Char is {}", c.to_string());
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `putback_iterator`
  --> src/main.rs:10:13
   |
6  |     let mut putback_iterator = put_back(hello_iter);
   |         -------------------- move occurs because `putback_iterator` has type `itertools::adaptors::PutBack<std::str::Chars<'_>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
7  |     let mut already_putback = false;
8  |     for c in putback_iterator {
   |              ---------------- value moved here
9  |         if c == 'd' && !already_putback {
10 |             putback_iterator.put_back('!');
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

How would I loop over the characters and perform a `put_back`? I can't find any worked examples using `put_back`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loops allow you to iterate over anything which implements [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). This trait defines `into_iter(self)` which consumes the object it is being called on and returns an iterator. This is true even when `self` is already an iterator (as it is in your code).

Thus, the `for` loop consumes the iterator, making it inaccessible within the loop.

An alternative is to use a `while let` loop instead:

```
use itertools::put_back; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let hello = "Hello world".to_owned();
    let hello_iter = hello.chars();
    let mut putback_iterator = put_back(hello_iter);
    let mut already_putback = false;
    while let Some(c) = putback_iterator.next() {
        if c == 'd' && !already_putback {
            putback_iterator.put_back('!');
            already_putback = true;
        }
        println!("Char is {}", c.to_string());
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecd11531ae87920d5f413eb0abfb3e8e)

Comment: Excellent! I am a C# programmer, and I always use IEnumerables in a foreach loop, never a while loop, so this did not occur to me.